What logarithm does the "discrete logarithm problem" refer to in the context of ECC?
In the case of integers, solving the DLP is finding a solution to $n=\log_b(x)$ given $b$ and $x$. There's a "log" in the equation, so the name DLP makes sense.
In the context of ECC, many texts reference the DLP when discussing key generation, $K = k \cdot G$. However, there aren't any "log"s being obviously used here or in the addition / doubling / multiplication operations. Where are the logarithms used in ECC? What operation or equation does the "logarithm" in DLP get its name from in the context of ECC?

I think you ask something like this; Is the term "Elliptic Curve Discrete Logarithm Problem" a misnomer? and Elliptic Curve Cryptography : discrete log and Diffie-Hellman

Great resources, much appreciated
